# How to import texture from Maya to unity?

Tags: unity, textures, maya, export

I am trying to export a model from Maya with animation but when I import into unity I am getting the model but the texture is not there. From the internet I found that while importing the model I need to enable media that also does not work for me.Is there any way that I can import Material texture in fbx file

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't directly encode the texture(s) into the fbx file itself.

So, you can export the fbx normally (without enable media) and import that into Unity.

Then, import the texture(s) into Unity and for the model's material, change its Albedo texture to the texture of the model.

[image: Albedo location]

If the model has multiple textures for different parts of it (hands, legs, etc.) then you have to assign each part a different material with a different Albedo texture.